# Reading csv file problems with the decimals

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have experienced the following error when I am reading a csv file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test/my_file.csv', sep = ';', decimal=".")
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test/my_file.csv', sep = ';', decimal=",")
```

Happens that the imported numbers are always like lower than they should be.

```
for example: 376362691 -> 3.763627
```

I can not change my csv file because it does has the right number. How can I import it properly to my python notebook?

I tried to change decimal (',' or '.') but the same mistake continues.

In my csv file looks like this:

```
index   C    V     t                    A
1     str1   27  2.269.511.284  376.362.691
2     str2   64  1.082.040.323  1.532.261.335
```

However, in my data frame when I import I either have

```
A    
376.362.691
1.532.261.335
```

or

```
A
3.76362691
15.32261335
```

While in my excel file the numbers mean this:

```
A
376362691
1532261335
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of your file. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't follow. How does it look like in your CSV and what are you expecting the output to look like?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in my csv it looks like with . separating but it means just the whole number. I guess the way that I am importing is causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've confused the `decimal` argument with `thousands`:

```
data = pd.read_csv(
    'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test/my_file.csv', 
    sep = ';', 
    thousands="."
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was totally lost